# Define listModel on button press

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist

So I am making a programm that contains this chunk of code

```
final ListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
btnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        listModel = MySQL("SELECT * FROM catalogos WHERE id = '" +
                           searchField.getText() +
                           "' OR name LIKE '%" +
                           searchField.getText() +
                            "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" +
                           searchField.getText() + "%'", "SELECT");             
    }
});

btnBuscar.setBounds(336, 11, 89, 23);
searchPanel.add(btnBuscar);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(10, 44, 316, 185);
searchPanel.add(scrollPane);
JList list = new JList(listModel);
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

As you can see I create a ListModel variable and then want to use it on button press. The function MySQL returns a listModel.

I then want to create a list and give it the elements inside the listmodel. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Don't build SQL queries like that, use a PreparedStatement!

Comment: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Could you explain it in a simpler language?I'm spanish and my english is not very good.

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL

Comment: I still dont understand the difference. In the option without the preparedStatement, you directly send the code to the MySQL function, and with the preparedStatement, you pass it through it?

Comment: SQL injections can let an evil user run arbitrary SQL on your database, stealing or changing the information stored there. PreparedStatements automatically stop users from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the SQL concerns, you are trying to reassign a `final` variable. You should make `listModel` a field (instance variable) instead of a final local variable so that your actionListener can access *and* change it.

Instead of

```
public class YourClassName {
  public ? yourMethodName() {
    final ListModel listModel = new DefaultListMode();
    JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
    ...
```

You would write

```
public class YourClassName {
  private ListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
  public ? yourMethodName() {
    JButton btnBuscar = ...
```

Comment: how do I do that?I'm quite new to programming, so sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 2):

- please read [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)
- try [examples](http://java2s.com/Code/SQL/CatalogSQL.htm)

shortcut for example

```
    try {
        String sqlSyntax = "SELECT * FROM ........";
        Statement stmt = myDbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsts = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSyntax);
        while (rsts.next()) {
            final String str = rsts.getString(1); // or another data types
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listModel.add(str.trim());
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // exeption handling
    } finally {
        try {
            rsts.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // not important  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand everything but the SwingUtilities and the run()

Comment: @user1178729 all updates to the Swing GUI must be done on EDT, sure your code example showing SQL from ActionPerformed, in this case are all updates done on EDT without invokeLater, more about EDT in tutorial Concurency in Swing